# Why are the anthropometric units (which are about as big as we are) as large as they are relative to their corresponding Planck units?

Tags: dimensional-analysis, physical-constants

This might have some duplicated inquiry that [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/1586/what-if-physical-constants-were-increased-or-decreased) [or this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/78684/why-is-it-meaningless-to-speak-about-changes-in-a-dimensional-constant) had, and while I think I have some of [my own opinions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_units#Planck_units_and_the_invariant_scaling_of_nature) about it, I would like to ask the community here for more opinions.

So referring to [Duff](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0208093) or [Tong](http://www.coursehero.com/file/p2q03qm/It-has-the-value-k-B-1-381-10-23-JK-1-In-some-sense-there-is-no-deep-physical/), one might still beg the question: Why is the speed of light 299792458 m/s? Don't just say "because it's defined that way by definition of the metre." Before it was defined, it was measured against the then-current definition of the metre. Why is $c$ in the ballpark of $10^8$ m/s and not in the order of $10^4$ or $10^{12}$ m/s?

A similar questions can be asked of $G$ and $\hbar$ and $\epsilon_0$.

To clarify a little regarding $c$: I recognize that the reason that $c\approx10^9$ m/s is that a meter is, by no accident of history, *about* as big as we are and a second represents a measure of how fast we think (i.e. we don't notice the flashes of black between frames of a movie and we can get pretty bored in a minute).

So light appears pretty fast to us because it moves about $10^9$ lengths about as big as us in the time it takes to think a thought.

So the reason that $c\approx10^9$ m/s is that there are about $10^{35}$ Planck lengths across a being like us ($10^{25}$ Planck lengths across an atom $10^5$ atoms across a biological cell and $10^5$ biological cells across a being like us). Why? And there are about $10^{44}$ Planck times in the time it takes us to think something. Why?

Answer those two questions, and I think we have an answer for why $c\approx 10^9$ in anthropometric units.

The other two questions referred do **not** address this question. [Luboš Motl](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/3666/37102) gets closest to the issue (regarding $c$), but he does not answer it. I think in the previous EDIT and in the comments, I made it (the question) pretty clear. I was **not** asking so much about the **exact** values which can be attributed to historical accident. But there's a reason that $c \approx 10^9$ m/s, not $10^4$ or $10^{12}$.

Reworded, I suppose the question could be "*Why are the anthropometric units (which are about as big as we are) as large as they are relative to their corresponding Planck units?*" (which **is** asking a question about dimensionless values). If we answer those questions, we have an answer for not just why $c$ is what it is, but also why $\hbar$ or $G$ are what they are.

Comment: For dimensionless constants, that's a question commonly called the *hierarchy problem* in a QFT context. For dimensionful constants, as it stands, it's kind of silly since nothing makes us prefer the metre over the inch.

Comment: Related (though not exhaustively covered): ["_Understanding the “$\pi$” of a rotating disk_", PSE/q/121889](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/121889/understanding-the-pi-of-a-rotating-disk)

Comment: well @ACuriousMind, the metre is a little bit closer to the height of a human being.  we certainly prefer a metre or foot over the Angstrom.  and we prefer a second as a unit of time over a nanosecond.

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/56973/2451 and links therein.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson What we prefer depends on context and in any case human preference does not imply validity. So the value of $c$ in metres is no more 'correct' than its value in e.g. beardseconds or Astronomical Units.

Comment: @Wouter, i totally understand that Nature doesn't give a rat's ass what units we choose to use to measure stuff with.  but the meter is about as big as we are and the second is about the time we need to form a thought.  so the question could come out as "*why are there about $10^{35}$ Planck Lengths across an organism such as us and why does it take something like $10^{44}$ Planck Times for us to form a thought?*"  if we can answer those questions, we have an idea why $c$ moves about $10^9$ human lengths in the time a human forms a simple thought.

Comment: the first question (about $10^{35}$ Planck Lengths in the ballpark of a meter) might be broken down to three questions.  for physicists: why are there about $10^{25}$ Planck Lengths in the size of atoms (approx the Bohr radius)?  for microbiologists: why are there about $10^5$ atoms across one dimension of a typical biological cell?  for biologists: why are there about $10^5$ cells across one dimension of a conscious and sapient being like humans?

Comment: user12262 wrote: "_Related (though not exhaustively covered): "Understanding the “$\pi$” of a rotating disk", PSE/q/121889_" -- Oops!, sorry, I had misread the title of this question as asking about "dimension- **less** constants", of course. Now addressing your actual question instead: I doubt that "_value of a dimensionful constant_" is a meaningful notion at all, since it depends on arbitrary choices of "units". Physics is done entirely in terms of dimensionless real number ratios.

Comment: @user12262, i tried to address your suggestion about "*consider[ing] changing the question title accordingly and/or asking instead about something you don't know yet.*".

Comment: robert bristow-johnson: "_@user12262, i tried to address your suggestion [...]_" -- (I first checked whether the question title had changed; when I noticed that it had not, I figured that at least the "_EDIT_" should be interesting ...) "_why $c \approx 10^9$ in anthropometric units._" -- Well, that's a question about "Why humans work and appear the way they do?". From a physics perspective this may relate to phrases (which I think I've read somewhere) such as "_(scale of) emergence_", or "_(at which ratios) difference in quantity turns to difference in quality_". (I know little about either.)

Comment: well @user12262, i am convinced that only by answering the $10^{35}$ question and by answering the $10^{44}$ question will we ever be able to answer the $10^9$ question.  (and if we can additionally answer the $10^8$ question regarding the Planck mass, then we also have answers for why $G$ and $\hbar$ are about what they are.)

Comment: robert bristow-johnson: "_the $10^{44}$ question [...] to form a thought_" -- That's hard; but it may be "factorized" into a question about "ingredients of thought", i.e. the $$\frac{G~m_e^2}{\hbar~c} \approx ?$$ question above (which I'm sure can be addressed at PSE, if it wasn't already); and another about "emergence/reduction of thought itself", i.e. a $$\text{Bohr duration / in anthropometric units} \approx \frac{\hbar}{m_e~\alpha} / \text s~ \approx  10^{-19}$$ question. The latter may receive (for now) more interest at other SE venues, but note http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/14959

Comment: Why everybody answering about units? Question not about units, but just about why speed of light is what we have, but not 10000 less or bigger? Does not matter which units.

Looks like nobody has the answer, but everybody wants to put smart comments :(

Comment: actually @Zlelik, it appears that you missed the point of the question.  if the speed of like becomes 10000 (whatever units) less or bigger, if all of the dimensionless constant remain unchanged, we would not notice any difference.

Answer (score 9):

You are correct in that the core of your question is indeed nontrivial, but you need to be a bit more subtle than that. The fundamental constants don't "take" values - they are what they are, and that's that. It is valid to ask "how did this 3×10<sup>8</sup> number come about", but the answer lies less with the speed of light than with the units we use to measure it. The real question, then, is

> why did we choose units of length and time such that the speed of light has a value of ~3×10<sup>8</sup> in those units?

Now, the gritty details of why we chose, say, the meter over the yard, are not really that important, and the reasons for those choices are historical - but mostly, we just had to choose *something*. As you've realized, these gritty details don't really matter; what really matters is the rough ballpark size of those units.

So, why did we choose the meter as the fundamental unit? Quite simply, because we ourselves are roughly meter-sized. This also came to mean that the world we built around us was also roughly meter-sized, so most of the things we measure in everyday life are roughly meter-sized.

On the other hand, we are made of atoms, and the size of atoms is a (fairly) fundamental constant of physics (particularly the Bohr radius $a_0$, which is a function of $ħ,\epsilon_0$ and $m_e$, and which is a good "standard atomic radius"). Let me pose, then, a similar question to yours,

> why is the 'standard' size of atoms, $a_0$, roughly 5×10<sup>-11</sup> m?

and rephrase it as before:

> why did we choose units of length which are roughly 2×10<sup>10</sup> times the 'standard' atom?

Since our units were chosen because we ourselves are about that size, the real question is therefore

> **why are humans roughly 2×10<sup>10</sup> 'standard' atoms tall?**

The reason I call this the 'real' question is that this is actually (at least in principle) an answerable question. However, it is not a physics question! It is a question about biology and about evolution, and it's not clear what the balance between those two is.

There is some sort of 'allowed' range of lengthscales in which intelligent life is possible (it is hard to imagine intelligence at the level of tens of atoms, and also at the star-sized lengths of 10<sup>19</sup> atoms), but just how broad this range is is a hard question in biology. There is also the historical, evolutionary question of how we came to occupy our particular spot on that range, and that is also a hard question. This is also made much more complicated by the anthropic-principle fact that we only know one instance of intelligent species.

On balance, then, we don't really know the answer to your question. But at least it is possible to ask the right question.

Comment: Emilio, you are thinking along the same lines as me.  but there *is* a question for physicists: why is the Bohr radius (approx the size of atoms) $10^{25}$ times bigger than the Planck Length?  and, i would bet, that physicists might have some information for the microbiologists about why there are about $10^5$ atoms across a biological cell, and maybe even why there needs to be about $10^5$ cells across one dimension of a being like us.  then we can ask why our brains function at the speed that they do: why there are about $10^{44}$ Planck times in about the time we can form a thought.

Comment: For why humans are the size they are, see the paper I link to in this [other answer](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/44284/are-we-big-or-small/126400#126400)

Comment: Thank you for clarifying OP's question for me. Asked in that way, it is indeed nontrivial. Very nontrivial even, especially since - like you say - we can only comment on the way things *currently* are on *our planet*.

Comment: okay @alemi, i'm looking at $$ L_H \sim \left( \frac{\hbar^2}{m_e e^2} \right) \left( \frac{ e^2 }{ G m_p^2 } \right)^{1/4} $$ and i want to express all quantities in terms of their Planck units.  i'll get back.

Comment: @robert bristow-johnson: "_there_ **is** _a question for physicists: why is the Bohr radius (approx the size of atoms)_ $10^25$ _times bigger than the Planck Length?_" -- Yes, that is certainly a question of great physics interest. Note that it is a question about a dimension- **less** quantity (i.e. plainly a real number value). And btw.: at least as far as I know it does **not** follow from the definition of (how to measure) this quantity that the values which would be found, trial by trial, had to be equal to each other (such that the quantity could rightfully be called "_a constant_").

Comment: @user12262, so far nothing you have told me is anything i hadn't known before.  i *know* it's a question about a dimensionless quantity $\frac{a_0}{l_P} \approx 10^{25}$.  i think that this **is** a constant and any small trial-by-trial variation you might have is experimental error or "noise".

Comment: @robert bristow-johnson: "_user12262, so far nothing you have told me is anything i hadn't known before. i know it's a question about a dimensionless quantity_" -- Then please consider changing the question title accordingly and/or asking instead about something you don't know yet. (For instance: the value of the ratio $$\frac{G~m_e^2}{\hbar~c}$$ that might be found in the **next** trial ...) "_i think that this is a constant and any small trial-by-trial variation you might have is experimental error or "noise"._" -- Something might be learned from the applicable systematic uncertainties, too.

Comment: @user12262 Can I, sincerely, ask you to tone down the typographical emphasis? It is dizzying and distracting, and it honestly [detracts from the clarity of your text](https://www.prismnet.com/~hcexres/textbook/high.html).

Comment: @Emilio Pisanty: "_Can I, sincerely, ask you to tone down the typographical emphasis? It is dizzying and distracting [...]_" -- I use the available appearance-modifying features, quite consistently (I hope), in order `1.`to mark quotations to which I reply, `2.`to indicate and cope with the (at times almost dizzying) number of notions for which I have no satisfactory definition (but which are used by other commenters nontheless), and `3.`for highlighting elements within my own writing. I heartily support `User:Options` for you to render my comments without any such features, if you so prefer.

Comment: hey @alemi, i'm having dimensional trouble with $$ L_H \approx \left( \frac{\hbar^2}{m_e e^2} \right) \left( \frac{ e^2 }{ G m_p^2 } \right)^{1/4} $$.  is cgs electrostatic units (esu) implied?  because i think it needs a couple of $\epsilon_0$ in there for my SI brain to grok it.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson, yeah to get the corresponding SI equation replace both instances of $e^2$ with $e^2/4 \pi \epsilon_0$

Answer (score 1):

Every dimensionful constant is a comparison to some standard. The oldest standards were based on the sizes of a typical person, because most full-grown people are more or less the same size and you always have your body with you. That's where we got the cubit and the foot. You still measure the height of a horse in hands. There are lots of other units which were historically convenient: for example, an acre is (I believe) the amount of land that a horse can plow in a day. Obviously if you want to be precise, this definition depends on whether you plow on a short winter day or a long summer day, whether your plow is dull or sharp, whether your field is soft or rocky, whether your horse is old or young. But if you have a forty acre plot of land, you know that you'll need to hire a second plow to get it all plowed and planted in under a month.

As engineering got better, it started to matter that not everyone was the same size, and better standards started to appear. This happened haphazardly pretty early — there is a passage in the Old Testament about a surveyor using a measuring rod to tell the size of something or other, so even in the cubit days people knew better than to crawl around putting elbow to fingertip — but the actual sizes of the standards probably still wandered over the years. The meter was an effort to move away from these "variable" standards by establishing a reference to which all people on earth have equal access: the meter was originally one ten-millionth of the distance from the earth's north pole to its equator. But this is an overly optimistic definition, too: that path length depends, slightly, on the longitude, and would be very challenging to actually survey for practical reasons. It's a better standard than the length of the king's arm, but not perfect.

The second has the same sort of history: it was originally intended as a convenient fraction of a 24 hour day. But it's *not* a convenient fraction of the interval between sunrises, since the sunrise comes earlier and later through the year; nor is it a convenient fraction of the interval between starrises (the "sideral day," shorter than the mean solar day by about four minutes), nor moonrises, nor any other obvious brief interval.  It takes a year of averaging before you can properly talk about a "mean solar day." Then you run into the fact that there are not an integer number of days in a year, requiring an extra day in leap years, nor are there an integer number of days in four years, requiring leap years to behave differently every four centuries.  A calendar error of one day in four centuries is comparable to a clock error of one second per day. It takes care to define the second relative to a "natural" reference interval.
And once you have defined the second relative to the length of a day, you discover that the length of the day is not really constant. Big earthquakes change the earth's moment of inertia; the 2011 earthquake in Japan lengthened the day by a few milliseconds.

If we lived on a different planet with a different circumference and a different day, these same sensible but arbitrary choices for natural reference lengths and times would have given us a different numerical value for the speed of light, and for the other constants.

Answer (score 0):

I can always choose units where $c = 1$. This is almost always done in context of General Relativity, Special Relativity and Quantum Field Theory. As ACuriousMind said in the comments above, how we measure quantities tells us nothing useful about the physics of it, since units can be rescaled.

As of why the speed of light is in the order of $10^8$? In my eyes, it is simply because compared to ordinary speeds where humans are used to, the speed of light is simply almost $10^8$ greater!

Edit: You have asked in the comments why human speeds are so small compared to $c$. Well recall that the speed of light is the speed a massless particle travels through the universe. For massive particles you need energy to accelerate them close to c. Humans are a collection of massive particles and hence you require a lot of energy to accelerate them at those high speeds. That energy is way too high than what we extract out of food/fuel etc.

Comment: It may well be that I misunderstand what you want to say with "constructed from the **3** fundamental constants", but hasn't the complete Standard Model **25** dimensionless constants? Plus the cosmological constant in GR makes 26 dimensionless constants we at present don't know how else to get than to measure them.

Comment: I just found [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_constant#Table_of_universal_constants). Apparently they are called ***universal*** constants and not fundamental. I'm under the impression that all other constants of nature can be constructed from these. I might well be wrong though. I will look this up more when I'm home.

Comment: BTW, i am pretty familiar with the existence of that web page from John Baez about the number of fundamental constants.  i confess i don't know enough about the physics of the Standard Model to know what all those coupling constants in those whatever matrices are about.  and i also know about Planck Units.  in fact, i am really couching this question in terms of the size of things w.r.t. Planck units.

Comment: one thing, @PhotonicBoom, i know that they do this with electrostatic cgs units by eliminating $\epsilon_0$ by use of the definition of unit charge (the "esu" or "statcolomb"), but in principle you can do the same with $c$ and $\hbar$ and $G$ (which is what Planck units do). but i am convinced that "**charge**" is a root or base dimension of physical "stuff" as is **time**, **length**, and **mass**.  so i think you need to add $k_e$ or $\epsilon_0$ to your list of the "fundamental constants". and for you, i would ask "why are '*ordinary speeds humans are used to*' about $10^{-8} c$?"

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson I deleted the constants paragraph as I'm not so sure anymore. Also you were right about $e_0$ at least. I also added another paragraph to address your other quetion in the comments.

Comment: @PhotonicBoom: "*You have asked in the comments why human speeds are so small compared to $c$*" but the question was a *little* more specific.  why $10^{-8} \ c$ instead of $10^{-12} \ c$ or $10^{-4} \ c$?